# How to make a single item list look like a regular paragraph with CSS only

Tags: html, css

I have a place where the number of items in a list is dynamic and I'd like to not have a single item list because it looks kind of funny.

I could detect that condition in JavaScript and style it accordingly but I'd like to know if it's doable in CSS only.

I can't use [:only-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) because I need to target the `ul` and, **as most CSS devs know**, there's no way to select upwards in CSS to set its padding to 0. Hacking negative margin on the li would only work for specific browsers/settings.

```css
ul.single-item{
  padding: 0;
}
ul.single-item li{
  list-style: none
}

li:only-child {
  list-style: none
}
```

```html
<p>I'm just a paragraph</p>

<ul class="single-item">
  <li>I have a hardcoded single-item class</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>I don't have a hardcoded class</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something else with two items, no CSS classes here</li>
</ul>
```

Do I have to resort to JS to add a `single-item` CSS class?

Comment: I think you try size attribute of html select element

Comment: instead of setting a padding on the list you could set it on the list-items?

Comment: as a side note, you cannot use negative padding, only negative margin

Comment: Why do you need to target the `ul`? You can overwrite all of the `ul` styles in the specific `li:only-child` CSS.

Comment: **YOU DO NOT** need to target the `ul` to solve the problem you are describing here.

Comment: @Martin If you don't think you do, please post an answer explaining how to do it without hard coding values for margin/padding

Comment: To whoever thought this was a duplicate, I already know that there's no upwards selector in CSS, but was looking for a clever workaround.

Comment: @juan I have used position absolute strategy. Hope it would help you

Comment: @Krish Please read the entire post before commenting, I stated in the question that `there's no way to select upwards in CSS`

Comment: @JuanMendes I don't need to post an answer, Temani and Aaron have both given perfectly good answers that do not involve trying to find the parent element of the `li`. The point of my comment was that your question is trying to fix a problem at source, rather than *cascading* over it with later, more specific instructions (given to the `li`). Thanks.

Comment: @Martin Both their answers hard code a padding. Either by assuming the browser's default, or by modifying the browser's default (or the current ul/li). I was hoping to keep the browser's default padding intact and keep it working if it ever changes

Comment: @JuanMendes but the browsers default padding changes based on many external factors. You are criticising these answers because they use **the values you gave**. It takes you only a few seconds to replace their values with [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value). [And see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)

Comment: @Martin not sure what you mean by **the values I gave** I didn't mention any values

Comment: @JuanMendes for your current scenario the solution is not achievable with CSS only. As you mentioned CSS have no parent selector, negative margins will impact cross browsers compatibility in your case. Please, resort to JS to add a single-item CSS class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the default behavior of ul without padding and then use it inside the `li`

```css
ul{
  padding: 0;
}
ul li{
  list-style: none
}

ul li:not(:only-child){
  margin-left:40px;
  list-style: disc;
}
```

```html
<p>I'm just a paragraph</p>

<ul >
  <li>I have a hardcoded single-item class</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>I don't have a hardcoded class</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something else with two items, no CSS classes here</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are hard coding the padding on the `li`, I guess it will work, since it doesn't rely on a user agent's default style sheet, but I'd rather honor the user's style sheet. IF no better answer comes up, I'll accept it

Comment: @JuanMendes generally speaking it's good to not rely on default style and consider your own margin/padding to avoid any surprise in the future even if the default margin/padding for `ul` will most likely never change.

Comment: I disagree, I think you're hampering usability since the user expects padding on lists to be a certain amount and that's how they display on most other sites. This is even bad for accessibility. As I explained in the other similar answer, this would mean I would have to reset all my lists on my site, which I'd also prefer not to do. But yes, I understand some like to go that route.

Comment: @JuanMendes never build complexity based on what the user "expects". There are 3 billion users, most of them expect different things. And most of them will take what they're given by their browser, regardless of their expectation. I **expect** all browsers to  use `Referrer-Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin` but Google Chrome does not accept this value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the problem with not using `:only-child`. Yes, hacking negative `padding` to the `li` items might not work, but there are other ways to do this.

```css
ul > li:only-child {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p>I'm just a paragraph</p>

<ul>
  <li>I'm a single item, styled as a paragraph</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Here are multiple items</li>
  <li>They are, therefore, not styled as a paragraph</li>
</ul>
```

The default padding is `40px`. So why not use `position: relative`?
Correct me if I understood your question wrong.

Comment: You are not honoring the user's default list padding. This would look different than everywhere else in my site unless I modified all my lists to use the custom padding, I'd prefer to use the padding that the browser/user has chosen

Comment: Fair point. I have to admit that [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif)'s solution is more elegant.

Comment: But they both require that I change the user's default padding, or know the user's default padding

Comment: Let me take back my statement that you have a "fair point" until I fully understand what you mean. Because as I read it again I realized that I didn't understand it and got some questions: Why you would it look different anywhere else in your site? What do you mean by "I'd prefer to use the padding that the browser/user has chosen"?

Comment: If the user has a default padding, with their private user CSS, all other lists will have different padding unless I apply this technique to all my lists, which would not honor the user's

Comment: User stylesheets were removed from Chrome since 2014. In Firefox and Edge (and IE if you care about it) you have to do a fair amount of steps (pretty complicated steps for the "normal" user) to create a user stylesheet. Although I found no numbers so far, I feel confident to say that a user who uses Internet Explorer is 100x more likely to visit the site than a user who uses a custom stylesheet.

Comment: Also, **here is a solution to the problem**: if you are afraid of user stylesheets, then add `!important` to the parts which would break all other lists in your site. `!important` overwrites the user agent stylesheets.

Comment: Your language is a bit odd: "I'm afraid of style sheets, so I should use `!important`". Sorry, I stop listening if anyone suggests `!important` as a solution  :p

Comment: Well, yes. You are "afraid" of user stylesheets breaking your site... or rather your list stylings. And I don't suggest it. I suggest leaving it like it is and to not care about it at all. But since you don't talk to me anymore :(, good luck finding a way.

Comment: I'm thankful for your help, maybe you missed my sarcasm on the last comment, I just made it because a user could add `!important` to their style sheet and it always wins, so it's not a solution. I'll probably just add the class to the `ul` with JS or use Temani's answer since it's a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to do it in a new approach, absolutely positioning the `li` when there's only one item. But this approach has its own problems. This will work only if the single list item is so small such that it will not overlap other placeholders. So this method is not recommended if you are not sure the list item content will stay in single line always.

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  /*need a margin bottom to avoid the overlapping */
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

ul li:not(:only-child) {
  list-style: disc;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p>I'm just a paragraph</p>
<ul>
  <li>A short line</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something else with two items, no CSS classes here</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Long line Long line Long lineLong line Long line Long line Long lineLong lineLong line Long line Long line Long line Long line Long line Long line Long lineLong line Long line Long line Long lineLong lineLong line Long line Long line Long line Long lineLong line Long line Long lineLong line Long line Long line Long lineLong lineLong line Long line Long line Long line Long line</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something else with two items, no CSS classes here</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You realize that using `position: absolute` is a **very** bad idea? It takes things out of the HTML flow and trust me: you will run into trouble! `position: absolute` should be used with caution and only for specific problems. Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for more detail.

Comment: @JuanMendes did you think about wrapping? what if the item will take two lines? what if you have a bigger font-size? let's don't forget that you are applying the margin to all the `ul` not only the one with one child

Comment: Exactly @TemaniAfif. I can't recommend this answer **at all**!

Comment: @TemaniAfif No, I did not, good catch, too good to be true. I modified this example to show it with wrapping lines

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for pointing out the issue. I have updated my answer.